# VBA API to Retrieve a List of Child Windows of an Application Based on Window Titles

Tags: vba

I am attempting to use the 'EnumWindows' VBA API to enumerate a list of child windows with titles starting with the string 'Bán hàng' (Unicode: windowTitle = "B" & ChrW(225) & "n h" & ChrW(224) & "ng h" & ChrW(243) & "a*") of an application other than Excel. Subsequently, I aim to sequentially activate each window in the obtained list and simulate key presses such as <kbd>F5</kbd> (refresh window) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (close window). However, I am encountering the following issues:

1. The enumeration of child windows is inaccurate, consistently returning 6 results, even though there are more or fewer windows in reality.
2. I am unable to send key presses to the third-party application (tried using SendMessage).

Attached is a file containing code snippets that I've referenced online and attempted to modify. Any insights or corrections would be greatly appreciated.
I apologize if the question is not spelled correctly as I am using a translator to ask.

This is the code I used to try to solve the problem:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    ' Win32API_PtrSafe
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#End If
 
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Long = &H100 ' H?ng s? này d?i di?n cho s? ki?n b?m phím xu?ng (key down).
Private Const WM_KEYUP As Long = &H101   ' H?ng s? này d?i di?n cho s? ki?n th? phím lên (key up).
Private Const VK_F5 As Long = &H74  ' Mã phím cho phím F5
Private Const VK_MENU As Long = &H12 ' Mã phím cho phím Alt
Private Const VK_F4 As Long = &H73   ' Mã phím cho phím F4
Public Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2 ' H?ng s? cho s? ki?n th? phím
    
Private Type FindWindowTitleParameters
    #If VBA7 Then
        lHwnd                     As LongPtr
    #Else
        lHwnd                     As Long
    #End If
    sFullTitle                As String
    sSearchTitle              As String
End Type


#If VBA7 Then
Public Function FindWindowByTitle(sFindWindowTitle As String, Optional bSetFocus As Boolean = True) As LongPtr
#Else
Public Function FindWindowByTitle(sFindWindowTitle As String, Optional bSetFocus As Boolean = True) As Long
#End If
    'Usage Examples:
    '    FindWindowByTitle "returning*"
    '    FindWindowByTitle "*parent*"
    '    FindWindowByTitle "*Excel"
    '    FindWindowByTitle "Inbox*"
    '    FindWindowByTitle "Document1 - Word"
    '    FindWindowByTitle "Book1 - Excel"
    Dim SearchParameters          As FindWindowTitleParameters
    
    SearchParameters.sSearchTitle = sFindWindowTitle
    Call EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowProc, VarPtr(SearchParameters))
    
    FindWindowByTitle = SearchParameters.lHwnd
    If FindWindowByTitle <> 0 And bSetFocus = True Then
        '        Debug.Print FindWindowByTitle, SearchParameters.sFullTitle
        Call SetForegroundWindow(FindWindowByTitle)
    End If
End Function

#If VBA7 Then
Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal lHwnd As LongPtr, _
                                SearchParameters As FindWindowTitleParameters) As Long
#Else
    Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal lHwnd As Long, _
                                SearchParameters As FindWindowTitleParameters) As Long
#End If
    Dim sWindowTitle          As String
    Dim lRetVal               As Long

    sWindowTitle = Space(GetWindowTextLength(lHwnd) + 1)
    lRetVal = GetWindowText(lHwnd, sWindowTitle, Len(sWindowTitle))
    sWindowTitle = TrimNull(sWindowTitle)

    If InStr(SearchParameters.sSearchTitle, "*") = 0 Then
        'Exact Macth Search
        If sWindowTitle = SearchParameters.sSearchTitle Then
            SearchParameters.lHwnd = lHwnd
            SearchParameters.sFullTitle = sWindowTitle
            EnumWindowProc = 0
        Else
            EnumWindowProc = 1
        End If
    Else
        'Wildcard Search
        If sWindowTitle Like SearchParameters.sSearchTitle Then
            SearchParameters.lHwnd = lHwnd
            SearchParameters.sFullTitle = sWindowTitle
            EnumWindowProc = 0
        Else
            EnumWindowProc = 1
        End If
    End If

End Function

Public Function TrimNull(ByVal sInput As String)
    Dim lPos                  As Long

    lPos = InStr(sInput, Chr(0))
    If lPos Then
        TrimNull = Left(sInput, lPos - 1)
    Else
        TrimNull = sInput
    End If
End Function

Function GetWindowTitle(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As String
    Dim titleLength As Long
    Dim title As String
    
    titleLength = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
    title = Space(titleLength + 1)
    
    GetWindowText hWnd, title, Len(title)
    GetWindowTitle = TrimNull(title)
End Function

Public Sub GetWindowWithTitleStartingWith()
    Dim windowTitle As String
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    Dim hwndChild As LongPtr

    windowTitle = "B" & ChrW(225) & "n h" & ChrW(224) & "ng h" & ChrW(243) & "a*"

    ' Tìm c?a s? cha d?u tiên th?a mãn yêu c?u, True de SetForegroundWindow
    hWnd = FindWindowByTitle(windowTitle, False)

    If hWnd <> 0 Then
         ' Tìm c?a s? con d?u tiên c?a c?a s? cha
        hwndChild = FindWindowEx(hWnd, 0, vbNullString, vbNullString)
        SetForegroundWindow hwndChild

        ' G?i phím F5, c?n c? WM_KEYDOWN và WM_KEYUP
        SendMessage hwndChild, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0
        SendMessage hwndChild, WM_KEYUP, VK_F5, 0

        ' G?i phím Alt + F4, c?n c? WM_KEYDOWN và WM_KEYUP
        SendMessage hwndChild, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_MENU, 0  ' Alt
        SendMessage hwndChild, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F4, 0
        SendMessage hwndChild, WM_KEYUP, VK_F4, 0
        SendMessage hwndChild, WM_KEYUP, VK_MENU, 0

        ' Tìm c?a s? cha ti?p theo th?a mãn yêu c?u, False d? không SetForegroundWindow
'        hWnd = FindWindowByTitle(windowTitle, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you want to match Unicode window titles, maybe you should use the Unicode versions of the API functions. I.e. instead of [`GetWindowTextA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) -> [`GetWindowTextW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw), instead of `GetWindowTextLengthA` -> [`GetWindowTextLengthW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengthw), instead of `FindWindowA` -> `FindWindowW`, `FindWindowExA` -> `FindWindowExW`

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I tried the following code:
Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" -> Alias "GetWindowTextLengthW"
However, when executing, it always closes the Excel application entirely and restarts with a blank window.

Comment: Maybe you have to adjust other parts of your code too, maybe the documentation can tell you more about how the two functions differ